# geometry_msgs/Pose - data access

Tags: python, ros

I am new to ROS and am stuck with really a simple issue. I have a data on a rostopic being published as geometry_msgs/Pose. Let's say I want to take the position data (say x) as a number and store it into a variable. I am using python. Can someone suggest the correct syntax to exactly access this particular data? Any additional information is also appreciated especially where I can find the syntax to access all these different kinds of message formats.

Update: The issue I was having was that if I save the entire data as a variable, I can access it using the **"."** notation. Considering the data to be geometry_msgs/Pos, the callback function I initially wrote is

```
def getcallback(self,data):
    var = data.position
    self.var = data
```

Later, I tried to access it using

```
self.var.x
```

it was out of index saying Point has no attribute x.

But after struggling for sometime, I edited the callback function

```
def getcallback(self,data):
    var = data
    self.var = data
```

Now, I can access the variable using

```
self.var.position.x
```

I am not sure why one worked and not the other and would like to know if somebody can explain.

Edit: Being in rush, I think the question here is entirely unclear. I am aware of the publishing and subscribing nodes and rostopics. I have rewritten the question with some update to help make it clear.

Comment: You can use `rostopic info /topic_name` in a terminal to get details about the topic publishing the message. In this, you will also get the message type. So, you can use `rosmsg show Message_type` and get the description of the message.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach to store the data in some `variable_x` is as follows:

1. Create a file `listener.py`
2. Make it executable: `chmod 770 listener.py`
3. Paste this code into it:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import rospy
    from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose

    def callback(data):
        variable_x = data.position.x
        rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'I heard %f', variable_x)

    def listener():
        rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber('chatter', Pose, callback)
        # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
        rospy.spin()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        listener()
```

4. Run the application: `./listener.py`
5. Test it by typing into your bash:

```
    rostopic pub /chatter geometry_msgs/Pose "position:
      x: 3.1415
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 0.0"
```

To answer your other questions:
You can get information about the message definition from [docs.ros.org](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html).
Since your question is really basic, please first walk through the whole [tutorial section](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) of ROS.
In your case, I just adapted the [listener example](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).

Comment: I apologize if the question was unclear..I was in rush while typing. I am aware of the stuff here and unfortunately this was not the issue I was having...Thanks for the reply though.